# Created array of tuples to call functions but cannot get a return

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function, tuples

I've created some functions with return type Void -> UIImage and I've build a class "FilterApplier" to call function by order. The idea is that every function takes a picture and changes it. But as I added the first function to an array, it did not return the image. What is wrong? Wrote code in a playground, swift ver. 7.3.1. Help me out please :p

```
import UIKit

//Sample images initialization
let mous = UIImage(named: "moustache.png")!
let sampleImage = UIImage(named: "sample.png")!

//Moustache Filter
func moustacheMaker() -> UIImage{
    let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
    let top: UIImage = mous
    let bottom = sampleImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
// Now I draw images to context
bottom.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
top.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
// Here I return the new image
let changedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return changedImage
}
class FilterApplier{
    typealias FunctionType = Void -> UIImage
    var filters = [(Int, String, FunctionType)]()
    func add(funcOrder: Int, funcName: String, function: FunctionType) -> FilterApplier{
        filters.append(funcOrder, funcName, function)
        return self
    }
    func runByOrder(){
        filters.sort(){
            return $0.0 < $1.0
        }
        for filter in filters{
            filter.2
        }
    }
}

FilterApplier().add(2, funcName: "Moustache", function: moustacheMaker).runByOrder()
```

By the way: the compiler does not act like there is a mistake. Nothing happens ://

Comment: `filter.2` is the function.  You need to call it: `filter.2()`.

Comment: What good is it to run a filter function if you're not giving it any input and not doing anything with the output?

Comment: Indeed - i'm guessing it's just an example  :)  Also Evgeny, "funcName" is probably unnecessary

Comment: When you say "*swift ver. 7.3.1*" – you mean Swift 2, right? (*Xcode* version 7.3.1). If that's the case, then `filters.sort()` won't do anything as you're not using the output. I also have no idea how you're intending to get out the resultant image from your filter, given that you're creating a temporary instance of `FilterApplier` and `runByOrder()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Good point. You must update to modern Xcode, Evgeny.

Comment: @Hamish yes, i meant swift 2 there..
1. "filters.sort() won't do anything as you're not using the output" -> So I need to store the result of sorting to a variable and then use that variable in for loop? 
2. The Idea was to iterate through the array of functions which all change the smaple image. Can you explain me how can I realize my thoughts in this code? Do I need to set the return type of func runByOrder to UIImage? Actually I tried this and many bad things began to appear :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evgeny, I realize it was probably just an example.  As Vaca said, the problem is just:

```
filter.2()
```

However just FYI one of many solutions here would be this...

Don't forget, in Swift you have to use Extensions **all the time, everywhere, for all reasons, and in every line of code**  :)

```
Extension UIImage {
  filter(with: [(void)]) {
   for f in with { self = f(self) }
  }
}
```

then you can just

```
testImage.filter(with: [blur, fade, moustache])
```

But what you are really perhaps looking for is something like this...

```
[blur, fade, moustache].map({ test = $0(test) })
```

note too that you can easily save those "orderings".

```
let userChose = [blur, fade, moustache]

userChose.map({ testA = $0(testA) })
userChose.map({ testB = $0(testB) })
```

(You could do the same thing with the extension, `test.filter(with: userChose)` )

Once you get going you should check out the [syntax](https://www.natashatherobot.com/mutating-functions-swift-structs/) for mutating functions, too.

Comment: As far as I need to upload a code in Swift 2, I cannot migrate my code in Swift 3 :( Also, I found that in Swift 2 image objects are immutable, so I cannot use that line "self = f(self)". Or I made a mistake again?